# Why is -7 mod 3 = 2 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

I am coming from Java to Ruby and this  -7 mod 3 = 2  puzzles me

Comment: Why should it puzzle you ? It's true. -7 mod 3 = 2 mod 3 = -1 mod 3, etc. One particular representation has to be chosen however, and Ruby seems to choose the non negative one (vs java which seems to choose the one with the same sign as the first operand).

Comment: @alexandre Why so unpolite to the OP. Apparently he didn't know the fact, that was why he asked.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Well, Java tells me -1. -7 / 3 = -2 with -1 remainder. -2 * 3 = -6 - 1 = -7

Comment: I too was completely thrown by this since I was coming from java. I'm not entirely sure why Ruby has to be different for the sake of being different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because -7 minus 2 is a multiple of 3.

More specifically, the implementation of modulus used in that case happens to choose the positive modulus. Some implementations choose the modulus with the same sign as the first operand, others always choose positive, etc.

Comment: You can use `remainder()` in Ruby to get the same result as in Java. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation for a table listing implementation choices in different languages.

Comment: thx my understanding of modulo was -7 / 3 = -2 with -1 remainder. => -2 *3 = -6 + -1 = -7

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a number wheel with elements `{0, 1, 2}` going clockwise.

You start at 0, and move 7 places counter-clockwise because you have `-7` (If you had `+5 mod 3`, you'd move `5` places clockwise).

So, let's see where does that take us:

```
Current Number:  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7
Wheel Number:    0  2  1  0  2  1  0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

The mod function gives the remainder above the greatest multiple less than the first parameter.

If it were 7 mod 3, then 6 is the greatest multiple less than 7, so 1 is the answer (7-6)

As it is -7, then -9 is the greatest mulitiple less than -7, so 2 is the answer (-7- -9, or -7+9)